# string copy logic in C

Tags: c, string

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    char n[11]="19:02:56PM";
    //scanf("%s",n);
    //printf("%s",n);
    char a[2]="";
    a[0]=n[8];
    a[1]=n[9];
    printf("%s",a);
    return 0;
}
```

this code gives the output as `PM19:02:56PM`
which I was expecting to be `PM`.

Had only copied the last 2 characters, but not sure about the logic.

Comment: You need `a[3]` as size and not `a[2]` because you need 3 bytes of space (2 characters plus a null terminator).

Comment: It's actually a loophole in your compiler. Try your code at https://www.codechef.com/ide The output will be : `PM` As per your code

Answer (score 4):

`printf` keeps printing until it encounters a 0-terminator byte. Both `a` and `n` are on the stack. Your `a` does not have a 0-terminator anymore because you overwrite that with `a[1]=n[9]`. Judging by the output, the memory for `a` is placed right before that of `n` on the stack. `printf` prints the contents of `a`, then keeps going until it hits a 0-terminator, so it continues printing `n`, at the end of which it finally encounters the 0-terminator and stops. If `a` did not precede `n` in memory, you would get garbage output or worse, because there's no telling when it would finally hit a 0 byte.

Comment: Many thanks, Matthias. got the logic very well now.